# Remove numbers from string and create a new string

Tags: php, string

How can I remove numbers from a string like `"take_me_apart_12_13"` to make it `"take_me_apart"` and save the numbers `(12 & 13)` into an array?

I've tried things like `preg_split("/_/", $string)` but that breaks the whole structure of the string (instead of just removing the numbers and keeping the words and underscores. I've been looking for a php function to use for this sort of thing but I cannot find one that accomplishes this task.

I know I could do something along the lines of using a for loop and checking each character and creating a new string in there but I was hoping to avoid that. If it's the only possible solution though, I'll have to use it.

Comment: show some effort before ask any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this **[0-9]** with **_**

```
$data = "take_me_apart_12_13";
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $data , $matches);
print_r($matches);
echo $words = preg_replace('/_[0-9]+/', '', $data);
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/984403)**

OUTPUT :: **take_me_apart**